# ¿Cómo cargar diferentes archivos css y js en diferentes vistas Blade en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, css3, laravel-blade, blade

Estoy trabajando con la plantilla Admin LTE 3.0 y resulta que tengo una plantilla llamada **datatable.blade.php** que hereda de **layout.blade.php**.
Por medio de la directiva

> @yield('content')

Hago que dicha vista **datatable** se muestre, pero resulta que la vista datatable tiene sus propios estilos y cuando los incluyo en la vista layout entran en conflicto con los que trae **AdminLTE** y ya todo se desajusta.
Quería saber si existe una forma de que cada plantilla cargue sus propios estilos sin afectar los de la otra para evitar este problema.

[image: la]